# Play 2.3 Scala - How to validate json without a reference modal class

Tags: json, validation, playframework

I've seen many examples with pretty much everything one can need to understand how to validate json representation of a given simple model.
Official play documentation is very specific on the subject, covering from simple validations to transformers and combinators.

I'm just wondering how can I check json againts a given data type structure, like:

```
{
  title : "title1",
  tags  : ["funny", "others"],
  props : [
    { prop1: "val1" },
    { prop2: "val2" }
  ]
}
```

I'd like to check the previous json example, to validate if it has this structure:

```
title: String
tags:  Array[String]
props: Array[(String->String]  // ???
```

This is of course a simplification, since a case class would be as simple as:

```
case class Example1(title: String, tags: Array[String], props: Array[???])
```

As you can see, my questions has two parts:
- first, I want to properly use validation/transformation/reads or whatever API Play 2.3.x is ment to perform that kind of json validation without a model
- second, how to specify an array of simple key/value objects

Answer (score 1):

[Validation with Reads](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaJsonCombinators) does not require a model class.

```
val json = { ... }
val titleMustBeString: Reads[String] = (JsPath \ "title").read[String]
json.validate[String](titleMustBeString) match {
  case title: JsSuccess[String] => println(s"Title: $title")
  case err: JsError => println("Invalid json")
}
```

Comment: That's absolutely true, but IMO its an uncomfortable way to validate a json structure with many properties, since `json.validate` forces to repeat `[types]` already specified in the chain of `JsPath.read`'s.
I'm now implementing a solution based on `json.pickBranch`, `and` combinator and `json.transform`, but there's still no validation for properties with type array, like 
`props : [
    { prop1: "val1" },
    { prop2: "val2" }
  ]`